# Jquery remote method showing the email and mobile already exist on the edit page without change anything

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter with jQuery validation. I am using `remote` to check `mobile number` and `email id` is already available or not in the database.  So there is no issue when the user registers. I am getting the issue on the edit page.

On the edit page, I just change the `name` and `address` but  `mobile number` and `email id` both are showing already exist.  I haven't change mobile and email. I know it will call the controller to check mobile and email are available or not but is there any other way to handle this issue?

I mean, not to check the previous data and check current data if the user enters anything in the field.

I want to check user against the database when creating the account, but NOT check user against the database when editing the account.

```
$("#edit_member").validate({
  errorElement: 'div',
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      alphabets: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      Email: true,
      remote: {
        url: baseUrl + "/AddMember/isEmail",
      }

    },

    phone: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      remote: {
        url: baseUrl + "/AddMember/isMobile",
        // async: false 
      }
    },


    address: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10

    }
  },

  messages: {
    email: {
      remote: "Email already Exists"
    },
    phone: {
      remote: "Mobile no already Exists"
    },
  },

  submitHandler: function(form) {//form.submit();}

});
```

**Controller**

```
function isEmail()
    {
        $email = trim($this->input->get('email'));
        $result = $this->addmember_model->isEmail($email);
        if($result)
        {
            echo $msg = "false";            
        }
        else
        {
            echo $msg = "true"; 
        }   
    }

    function isMobile()
    {
        $mobile = trim($this->input->get('phone'));
        $result = $this->addmember_model->isMobile($mobile);
        if($result)
        { 
      echo $msg = "false";  

        }
        else
        {
            echo $msg = "true";
        }   
    }
```

**Model**

```
function isEmail($email) 
    {
        $result = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email,'is_status'=>1])
                           ->get('members')
                           ->row();
        return $result;
    }

    function isMobile($mobile)
    {
        $result = $this->db->where(['phone'=>$mobile,'is_status'=>1])
                           ->get('members')
                           ->row();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: When you get a hit on either mobile or email, check if the record has the current users id or not.

Comment: So I have to send the current user id to the controller. right? So how can i send the user id?

Comment: _"So how can i send the user id?"_ - Since I don't know anything about your application, I can't help you with the specifics there. But when you check the result, you should do something like: `if ($result->id != $editedUser)` or pass it to the query and add it as a `WHERE id != theEditedUsersId` (but with CI's db-class, of course)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I am the super admin and if I have to change the details of the employee then I am getting the "Already exists"?  Do you mean I have to store the id in the session?

Comment: Since you're editing a user, you must get the user id as well, or you wouldn't be able to update that users record in the database. So you must check if the mobile or email exists in the database _except_ for that specific user id.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Yes, I have a user id,I will try this. I have to create one more function with user id and data which come from the remote and check with database.right?

Comment: No need to create another function. Just pass the user id as an argument to your existing functions. You can add it like this: `function isEmail($userId = 0)` and then check `if ($result->id != $userId)`. Then you can use it both with or without passing a user id to it. If you're not passing an id, then it will check if it exists at all (like if a new user is added) and if you pass the id, it will check if someone else, except that user, has it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I am confused, the remote function will pass the only one variable. How can I pass user id to email function and mobile function?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to determine if the page is Editing or Creating and set a variable as such.  You could look at a URL segment with the URI Class.

```
<?php
   $create = ($this->uri->segment(3) == "create") ? TRUE : FALSE;
?>
```

Then use PHP to write the relevant rule(s) for that particular version of the View.

```
$("#edit_member").validate({
    ....
    rules: {
        ....
        email: {
            required: true,
            Email: true,
            <?php if ($create) : ?>
            remote: {
                url: baseUrl + "/AddMember/isEmail",
            }
            <?php endif; ?>
        },
        ....
```

The above only works when this part of the JavaScript is in the View file and not included from an external JavaScript file.

Otherwise, if `.validate()` is part of an externally included JavaScript file, then you can [use the `.rules()` method instead](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

After the JavaScript includes (after `.validate()` invoked), programmatically remove the `remote` rule.

```
<?php if ($edit) : ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[name="email"]').rules('remove', 'remote');
        });
    </script>            
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this.

Comment: if I remove remote then how can admin identify the user entering the data is unique?

Comment: I don't see where your OP is asking to check if data is unique when Admin is editing.  In fact, you ask that it NOT be checked when editing:  *"On the edit page, I just change the name and address but  mobile number and email id both are showing already exist. I haven't change mobile and email. I know it will call the controller to check mobile and email are available or not but is there any other way to handle this issue?"*

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but I haven't said that I want to remove the remote method. If I want to remove the remote method then I will remove directly. I have two validation first for add member and second for edit_member. I can refer you answer for my future reference. but as of now, my issue is different.

Comment: @user9437856, then you need to write a better question.  As written, it sounds exactly like you want to check user against database when creating the account, but NOT check user against database when editing the account.

Comment: Quote:  *"I want to check user against the database when creating the account, but NOT check user against the database when editing the account."* ~ and that is exactly what my answer is trying to show you.  In my first suggestion, you only write out the `remote` rule when using the form for creating the account, and in my second suggestion, you remove the `remote` rule when using the form for editing the account.  When using `remote`, you're "checking user against the database", and when removing `remote`, you're "NOT checking user against the database".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186954/discussion-between-user9437856-and-sparky).

Comment: Thanks for the information... The thing is, I am on edit page and email and mobile are already in the input field. Now I haven't changed anything in the email and mobile field and clicked on submit button then it's showing the error email and mobile already exist.
If I try to change anything in the email and mobile then first it will check in the database that the details which admin enter that already in the database or not.  if not then update successfully if found data then display the error message.

Comment: @user9437856, regardless, you don't have to use my answer exactly as written.  You could take it and modify it.  Instead of removing the `remote` rule, you could use `.rules()` method to change it into a different `remote` rule.  OR you could use the PHP to dynamically write different rules depending on if you're editing or creating.  Either way, simply **load different JavaScript dynamically by leveraging how the PHP is writing the page**.  If you need to do something else on the server, then the question has very little, almost nothing, to do with the actual client-side validation.